# Why does Json.NET fail to serialize a X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, json.net

Whenever I try to serialize an X509Certificate2 instance with Json.NET (without using its ISerializable implementation, but electing to ignore it), Json.NET throws an exception.

The exception message is "A member with the name 'CertContext' already exists on 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name."

I wrote a program that reproduces it:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var resolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            IgnoreSerializableInterface = true,
            DefaultMembersSearchFlags =
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty
        };

        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new X509Certificate2(), new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = resolver});
    }
}
```

After investigating, I noticed that X509Certificate2 implements a property called "CertContext" which hides a method with the same name in its base class, X509Certificate. How can I tell Json.NET to just take the most derived property, like it usually does?

Answer (score 4):

I recently came across a need to serialize instances of `X509Certificate2` in order to compare differences into two supposedly identical environments that were behaving differently. I was able to achieve serialization via the following `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Error = (s, a) => a.ErrorContext.Handled = true,
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
        IgnoreSerializableInterface = true
    }
}
```

Here's a complete working example which JSON serializes the first certificate in the local machine store and opens it:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

            try
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                var cert = store.Certificates[0];

                var path = Path.GetTempFileName();

                File.WriteAllText(
                    path,
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        cert, new JsonSerializerSettings {
                            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                            // Ignore serializtion errors
                            Error = (s, a) => a.ErrorContext.Handled = true,
                            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
                                // Ensures all properties are serialized
                                IgnoreSerializableInterface = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                );

                Process.Start(path);
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But unfortunately when trying to deserialize this serialized object, it fails

Comment: @HugoNavaKopp, yes, my use case was to serialize for diagnostic purposes to troubleshoot a problem. Future readers should be ware that deserialization is highly unlikely to succeed.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can employ converter:

```
public class X509Certificate2JsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(X509Certificate2);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var deserializedRaw = serializer.Deserialize<byte[]>(reader);
        var deserialized = new X509Certificate2(deserializedRaw);
        return deserialized;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
        object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        byte[] certData = ((X509Certificate2)value).Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, certData);
    }
}
```

And the test for it:

```
public class CertificateHolder : IDisposable
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(X509Certificate2JsonConverter))]
    public X509Certificate2 Certificate { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() => Certificate?.Dispose();

    public static X509Certificate2 CreateCertificate()
    {
        var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();
        var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=foobar", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
        var c = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));
        return c;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
class X509Certificate2JsonConverterTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Serialization()
    {
        var holder = new CertificateHolder();
        holder.Certificate = CertificateHolder.CreateCertificate();
        var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(holder);
        var holderRestored = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CertificateHolder>(str);
        var holderStr = holder.Certificate.ToString();
        var holderRestoredStr = holderRestored.Certificate.ToString();
        Assert.AreEqual(holderStr, holderRestoredStr);
        holder.Dispose();
        holderRestored.Dispose();
    }
}
```