# Save CodeFirst's property to Base64 string in EFCore but read back X509Certificate2 from EFCore?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

The `ThirdParty` model contain a property `Certificate`.  It is a datatype of `X509Certificate2` for source code use, but EFCore doesn't support it, meaning I have to convert it to `Base64 string` for EFCore database storage.  Then convert it back to `X509Certificate2` when reading from EFCore database.

How do we instruct EFCore to do this automatically with whatever property mapper?

```
public class ThirdParty
{
   public Guid ThirdPartyId { get; set; }
   public X509Certificate2 Certificate { get; set; }
   public string RawData { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

var certificate1 = new X509Certificate();
var thirdParty = new ThirdParty() { Certificate = certificate }
var certificate2 = thirdParty.Certificate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to add an *additional not mapped property* that will return the `X509Certificate2` object that will be created out of the `Base64` `string` that was read from database.
Therefore the `CertificateString` property is used only to save and read from data context and the `Certificate` property is for usage in your other logic.

```
public class ThirdParty
{
    private X509Certificate2 _certificate;



    public Guid ThirdPartyId { get; set; }

    // to write in data context only - only set it in production code
    public string CertificateString 
    {
        get
        {
            // return the Base64 string - is just pseudo code
            return _certificate?.ToString();
        }    
        set
        {
            _certificate = new X509Certificate2(value);
        }
    }

    // not mapped for data context - to read from data context only - only read fro
    public X509Certificate2 Certificate
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CertificateString))
            {
                return default(X509Certificate2);
            }

            return new X509Certificate2(CertificateString);
        }    
        private set
        {
            // will be set by CertificateString
        }
    }

    public string RawData { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

To not map a property you could use `[NotMapped]` as Data Annotation or `.Ignore(p => p.PropertyName)` in Fluent API.

Comment: I updated the post above by adding 3 more lines at the bottom.  I tried to figure out how to make it work by doing it the other way around but couldn't get it to work.  :-/

Comment: Which exceptions do you get?

Comment: Scratch that.  Found the problem, the debugger acts weird when I do `new X509Certificate2()`.  I accept your answer anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work. The `get` of the `CertificateString` is going to call the `get` of the `Certificate`, then the if statement is going to check the `CertificateString`. So it is going to call the `get` of the `CertificateString`. I think you already understand what is happening. This will create an infinite loop. And most of the time an StackOverFlowException.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it. Added a backend field to avoid the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, possibly look at [Why does Json.NET fail to serialize a X509Certificate2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684184/why-does-json-net-fail-to-serialize-a-x509certificate2) if you're having issues with serializing the cert.

```
public class Configuration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ThirdParty>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ThirdParty> builder)
    {
        // This Converter will perform the conversion to and from Json to the desired type
        builder.Property(e => e.Certificate).HasConversion(
            v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
            v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X509Certificate2>(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));
    }
}
```